# How to remove duplicate Event in xamarin.android binding?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I add a `aar` to xamarin.binding but it generate two same `event` and I use `jd-gui` and find that there is only one interface in the `aar`

how to remove one in the metadata.xml?

I know how to change the others but do not know how to remove one `event`

I know the manageType and manageReturn can change something but it can not remove the event.

the path of the `event` I can not find it right.
`path="/api/package[@name='com.xxx.A']/class[@name='C']/interface[@name='OnBLisntener']` is not right .

Comment: `the path of the event I can not find it right.` - this seems like a different question. I recommend creating a new question for that. So people who don't have any idea about duplicate events can see a question with an appropriate title, and maybe have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in [Troubleshooting Bindings / Problem: Duplicate custom EventArgs types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings#problem-duplicate-custom-eventargs-types)

> To avoid these conflicts, some metadata transformation is required. Edit Transforms\Metadata.xml and add an **argsType attribute** on either of the interfaces (or on the interface method):

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.ads.mediation']/
        interface[@name='MediationBannerListener']/method[@name='onDismissScreen']"
        name="argsType">BannerDismissScreenEventArgs</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.ads.mediation']/
        interface[@name='MediationInterstitialListener']/method[@name='onDismissScreen']"
        name="argsType">IntersitionalDismissScreenEventArgs</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='android.content']/
        interface[@name='DialogInterface.OnClickListener']"
        name="argsType">DialogClickEventArgs</attr>
```

My understanding is that there really are two event-handlers, you just aren't seeing them both.

If I am correct, you shouldn't try to *remove* one of the event-handlers. Rather, you should *rename* one of them (or both of them, for clarity), using `"argsType"`.

Comment: No there is only one interface but there are two methods which using the interface.` public static interface OnCameraChangeListener {
    void onCameraChange(CameraPosition param1CameraPosition);
    
    void onCameraChangeFinish(CameraPosition param1CameraPosition);
  }`

`public final void addOnCameraChangeListener(OnCameraChangeListener paramOnCameraChangeListener){} ` and `public final void removeOnCameraChangeListener(OnCameraChangeListener paramOnCameraChangeListener) {}`

Comment: another is a `set` 
there is add and remove another is `set`

`public final void setOnCameraChangeListener(OnCameraChangeListener paramOnCameraChangeListener) {}`

I think it is the parameter `OnCameraChangeListener` there is 3  which confilicts?

how to change the parameter's name?

Comment: The `argsType` are same so that I can not change them.

Comment: @daotian OK; then I don't how to fix. Please add those details to your question. Perhaps someone else will have an idea. Show exactly what appears in that part of Metadata.xml.

Comment: I think what you say is right.But the new question is how to find the path of the interface. I edit the question please check.